# How can I have an URI with two GET?

Tags: 8

I wrote my custom rest endpoint. I need to 2 URI both called with GET

- /api/item/{id} to get single item identified by ID
- /api/item to get the list of items.

i try with

```
  @RestResource(
    id = "my_id",
    label = @Translation("My label"),
    uri_paths = {
      "canonical" = "/api/item",
      "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/index" = "/api/item/{id}",
    }
```

into my class i have

```
class ApiRestResource extends ResourceBase {

    public function get($id = NULL) {
```

but only canonical URI is found. the message for the second URI is

```
"message": "No route found for \"GET /api/item/1\""
```

how can i have 2 GET in my class?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

you can create two resource files, one that receives the parameter and another that does not.

Example:

> demo_rest_api.info.yml.

```
name: Demo REST API
description: Define's a custom REST Resource
package: Custom
type: module
core: 8.x
```

> /src/Plugin/rest/resource/DemoResource.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\demo_rest_api\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;

/**
 * Provides a Demo Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "demo_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Demo Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/item"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class DemoResource extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * Responds to entity GET requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function get() {


      $response = ['message' => 'Hello, this is a rest service:'];

    return new ResourceResponse($response);

  }
}
```

> /src/Plugin/rest/resource/DemoResource_item_id.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\demo_rest_api\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;

/**
 * Provides a Demo Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "DemoResource_item_id",
 *   label = @Translation("Demo Resource item id"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/item/{id}"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class DemoResource_item_id extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * Responds to entity GET requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function get($id= null) {


      $response = ['message' => 'Hello, this is a rest service and parameter is: '.$id];

    return new ResourceResponse($response);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. I know but i don't understand why i can't manage multiple GET in the same class.  core.link_relation_types.yml works fine for "create" => POST and "edit" => PUT. It's a bug?

Comment: @FabioRiva if canonical is the only link that works for GET, per your own comment on my answer... then you will definitely need two resources.

Comment: You're either returning one resource of a list of them. Resource and ResourceList are 2 separate functions so should be separate resources anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RestResource documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rest%21src%21Annotation%21RestResource.php/property/RestResource%3A%3Auri_paths/8.4.x), uri_paths are:

> Key-value pairs, with link relation type plugin IDs as keys, and URL templates as values.

Your second uri_paths item needs a key to tell Drupal what kind of endpoint it is.

[core.link_relation_types.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.link_relation_types.yml/8.4.x) contains the available types.
In your case I'm going to hazard a guess that `item` is the most appropriate.

If that doesn't work, maybe try creating two classes.

Comment: Thank you Darvaner, i try item, index .... but only canonical path works for GET. PUT and POST work fine.

Answer (score 0):

this [page](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/custom-restful-api-drupal-8) , contains information that may interest you.

Just modify the path in your  file: .routing.yml

```
test_api.getitemid:
  path: '/api/item/{id}'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\test_api\Controller\TestAPIController::getitemid_example' }
  methods:  [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

test_api.getallitem:
  path: '/api/item'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\test_api\Controller\TestAPIController::get_example' }
  methods:  [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

In your file: TestAPIController

add the  functions

> getitemid_example

```
public function getitemid_example( Request $request, $id=null ) {

    $response['data'] = 'your id parameter is:'.$id;
    $response['method'] = 'GET';

    return new JsonResponse( $response );
  }
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer but this is not a RESTful resource. i would like to implement with a @RestResource-annotated plugin implementing ResourceInterface.

Comment: The problem has the "canonical" parameter.

The idea of using resources is that if you want to use the methods: GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE it has to be without parameters or with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think for the same operation, We need to create multiple files.

Request URL: http://localhost/drupal/product-list?search=abc

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Provides a resource to get view modes by entity and bundle.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "drupal_rest_api",
 *   label = @Translation("rest  api"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/product-list"
 *   }
 * )
 */


public function get( Request $request) {                        
        $search = \Drupal::request()->query->get('search');
        kint($search)   

}
```

You can be added multiple arguments without creating multiple files